# JQuery - loading multiple pages in one newly opened window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm total beginner in js and JQuery and have to complete such task:

I have to open new window with some document print preview. It is not a problem for single document, but there's a need to print more than one document. I was trying to do this like that:

```
var win = window.open("", "test", "width=700,height=600");
$(win.document).ready(function(){
    $(win.document).contents().load("here_my_action_with_changing_id");
})
});
```

but it only loads first document and I don't have any idea how to load one after another.
Also, it seems not to work on IE properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start with, you need to change this `$(win.document).ready` to `$(document).ready` - or indeed `$(function() { ... });` which is a shorter version of writing it.

Same goes for the load call, but you probably want to change the binding here so that on link clicks of a specific type, the window.open is called - rather than on the document ready event.

I would also suggest you create a single link for each document you wish to print - trying to print multiple documents from a single link would require quite a lot of effort and be fairly tricky to develop and synchronise

What you could then do is use the jQuery [`index`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) API to find the index of the `<a>` tag within the list of `<a>` tags, in order to generate an id to pass to your load call, so it knows which piece of content to load and subsequently print based on the link that was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery UI modal dialog with iframe to show ur preview to print. and on button click of the modal dialog u cud refresh the content of iframe to show next preview